# Change not reflecting on the ubuntu machine after the root volume size was changed in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have changed the root volume size of my instance through AWS Console and the change is reflecting there.

When I log into my ubuntu machine and run `'fdisk -l'` the previous disk capacity is shown.

Am I missing any other additional steps here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> After you increase the size of an EBS volume, you must use file
> system–specific commands to extend the file system to the larger size.

You can extend the volume using  `growpart` command and then resize the file system using `resize2fs` command.

Please refer https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html